# Golang mariadb select does not return signal error

Tags: mysql, go

i created a function in MariaDB which its body is:

```
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MY_ERROR_MESSAGE';
  RETURN 1;
END
```

Then in Golang, I tried to select this function, which must be done with an error.

```
dbResult := db.QueryRow("SELECT `function1`()")
    if dbResult.Err() != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error (%s)", dbResult.Err().Error())
    }
```

but the problem is that `Err()` is `nil` !!!!!!!!!! What is the problem !?
and `fmt.Printf` is not executed.

The funny part is that i created a procedure this time

```
BEGIN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MY_ERROR_MESSAGE';
END
```

and i used the same golang code to call it

```
dbResult := db.QueryRow("CALL `procedure1`()")
        if dbResult.Err() != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error (%s)", dbResult.Err().Error())
        }
```

but this time everything is OK !!! and `.Err` is not nil any more ! Why ???? What is the problem

Comment: What is the return (dbreturn)?